# Sending push notification to users in specific location on iOS (Background and killed)

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, location

I've been reading around SO about this and the only close question i've found is **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456570/parse-push-notifications-with-location-ios)**, which has 33 views and one zero-vote answer that might be correct. And its not exactly what i want. And i've found also **[this one](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/features/geotrigger-service/)**, but i'd like to know if there is a built-in way beforehand.

I'm trying to send notification to every user of my app that is in a specific area. For the sake of the discussion lets call that Brussels. When a user (lets say, Barcelona) uses my app, at some point I need him to trigger a notification to all the users in brussels. And when one or more of the guys in Brussel has followed the notification instructions, I need to send one new notification with new instructions to the Barcelona dude.

Is this in any way achievable at all with iOS? In only a couple of words :

**Make it so that an area generates notifications to all the users in it until someone follows the instruction. When that is done, one specific user recieves one notification. The app can be in background or even closed. Can we do that?**

If so, can anyone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: Unfortunately no, location based stuff is all handled on the client side.  You can send a **local** notification when a user when they enter or exit, but you can't send a remote notification to users in a certain area (unless you find a third party service that can perform it)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Core Location Region Monitoring for this. (You can solve this with Local Notifications instead of Push)

Read the guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/locationawarenesspg/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

- it is working when you app is not running in the background (killed)
- you have to use requestAlwaysAuthorization on iOS8

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll follow this link and give it a try. I've never used notifications so it'll take time, but i'll make sure to mark answer as correct if it ends up being so ;)

Comment: Sure, you have to add the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with the proper description to you .plist, follow the instructions and your delegate method will be called even if your app is killed. When it gets called just post a Local Notification.